# How to limit the rotation of a Quaternion.Slerp() Function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I have been working on a VR project in which a pair of eyes track a point in the world space. For starters, I am using the player's controller as the target. The eyes currently track exactly as I expect them to, however since they are eyes I would like to limit how far up/down and left/right they can look. I have tried to accomplish this using localEulerAngles, which seems to work, but once I enter the "wrong" if block the eye rotation never changes again, and therefore stays stuck. So I think that I need to force the rotation back into an acceptable limit, but I do not know how to properly do this. I also think there is probably a better way to do this whole thing that I am unaware of. Here is my current update function:

```
    void Update(){

    Vector3 direction = finger.position - this.transform.position;

    float angleX = transform.localEulerAngles.x;

    //this text is displayed in VR so that I can see while I test
    temp.text = transform.localEulerAngles.x.ToString();

    //this condition is for if the finger is held up in the air
    if (pointing)
    {
        //because of the way angles work, it is necessary to check what      CANT be?. 
        if (angleX > 15 && angleX < 350)
        {
            //what to do here?

        }
        else
        {
            //look at the finger
            this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(this.transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), 0.1f);
        }

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Mathf.Clamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) method to limit a float value between a minimum and maximum value, then reset the transform's X angle to the clamped value.

So your `Update` method becomes:

```
void Update() {

    Vector3 direction = finger.position - this.transform.position;

    float angleX = transform.localEulerAngles.x;

    //this text is displayed in VR so that I can see while I test
    temp.text = transform.localEulerAngles.x.ToString();

    //this condition is for if the finger is held up in the air
    if (pointing)
    {
        float clampedAngle = Mathf.Clamp(angleX, 15f, 350f);
        transform.localEulerAngles.x = clampedAngle;

        //look at the finger
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(this.transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), 0.1f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, you're `Quaternion.Slerp` method *may* need to take `transform.localEulerAngles` instead of `transform.rotation` but I'm not 100% sure. I've also read that this can cause issues being in `Update` and may need to be in `LateUpdate` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, I would have to try it to be sure, but I believe this will result in a problem with the euler angles. I don't NEED the rotation to be between 15 and 350, but I need to NOT allow anything between 15 and 350, due to the way x seems to be rotating.

Comment: I tried it out, sadly this does not work. you cannot simply set the localEulerAngles.x, though you can use localEulerAngles.set(), which doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you set the `rotation.x` then transform to euler, or something like that?